# Function is getting called multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I have an array of objects

```js
const data = [{
  Description: "confirm"
  Id: "1"
  Name: "confirm"
  Value: "VIP:confirm"
}, {
  Description: "validate"
  Id: "2"
  Name: "validate"
  Value: "VIP:validate"
}, {
  Description: "Sent"
  Id: "2"
  Name: "Sent"
  Value: "VIP:Sent"
}]
```

Now, I am trying to get the description by passing the value:

```js
const valuesObject = [
  "VIP:Confirmed",
  "VIP:Validated",
  "VIP:Sent"
]
```

Now, Values data is like

```js
const getDescription = (
  value: string,
  Values: Array < >
) => {
  let allValues = _.find(Values, item => item.Value === value)
  return resolve(allValues)
}

const resolve = (object) => {
  return object?.Description ? object.Description : object?.Name ?? ''
}
```

Now, here I am doing ,

```js
const status = valuesObject.map((value) => {
  return getDescription(value, data)
})
return status.join('/')
```

I was expecting it should return me Confirmed/Validated/Sent

It returns but function gets called multiple times. can any one help me with this ?

Comment: I have just edited..

Comment: Which _"function gets called multiple times"_?

Comment: getDescription is called multiple times because you have kept it inside map of valuesObject.

Comment: For a while, it seemed to me that you are working with Dart.

Comment: It should have get called there times but getting called multiple times

Answer (score 0):

Use `_.intersectionWith()` to get objects with the `Value` property that matches one of an array of values. Then map to get the `Description` or `Name`:

```js
const getDescription = (arr, values) => _.map(
  _.intersectionWith(arr, values, (o, v) => o.Value === v), // get all objects with matching values
  ({ Description, Name = '' }) => Description || Name // map to description / name / empty string
).join('/')

const data = [{"Description":"Confirmed","Id":"1","Name":"confirm","Value":"VIP:Confirmed"},{"Description":"Validated","Id":"2","Name":"validate","Value":"VIP:Validated"},{"Description":"Sent","Id":"2","Name":"Sent","Value":"VIP:Sent"}]

const valuesObject = ["VIP:Confirmed","VIP:Validated","VIP:Sent"]

const result = getDescription(data, valuesObject)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.19/lodash.js"></script>
```

Using lodash/fp you can generate the `getDescription()` function with `_.flow()`:

```js
const getDescription = _.flow(
  _.intersectionWith((o, v) => o.Value === v), // get all objects with matching values
  _.map(({ Description, Name = '' }) => Description || Name), // map to description / name / empty string
  _.join('/')
)

const data = [{"Description":"Confirmed","Id":"1","Name":"confirm","Value":"VIP:Confirmed"},{"Description":"Validated","Id":"2","Name":"validate","Value":"VIP:Validated"},{"Description":"Sent","Id":"2","Name":"Sent","Value":"VIP:Sent"}]

const valuesObject = ["VIP:Confirmed","VIP:Validated","VIP:Sent"]

const result = getDescription(data, valuesObject)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```